# Specifying maxItems for a List<List<Object>> using spring swagger.v3 ArraySchema annotation

Tags: java, swagger, springdoc, springdoc-openui

We are facing an issue where we are unable to use any variant of @ArraySchema to specify the limit of maxItems for the properties such as -

**List<List< obj >> test;**

**List<List<List< obj >>>> listOfTest;**

JSON Validation error:

*Semantic error at test.items
Arrays must have 'maxItems' property defined*

*Semantic error at listOfTest.items.items
Arrays must have 'maxItems' property defined*

Tried following -

**@ArraySchema(schema = @ArraySchema(schema =@Schema(description = "test), maxItems =2))**

**@ArraySchema(arraySchema = @ArraySchema(schema =@Schema(description = "test), maxItems =2))**

**@ArraySchema(arraySchema = @Schema(//with type property)**

But all the above flavors fail due to incompatibility error.

*Incompatible Types : Found: ArraySchema, required: Schema*

Project is using springdoc openapi version 1.6.5

Can someone please specify how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin it can be done like this:

```kotlin
    @Schema(description = "Your DTO")
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    data class YourDTO(
        @JsonProperty
        @field:Schema(
            description = "Date",
            type = "date-time",
            example = "2023-12-30 09:00",
            required = true
        )
        @NotNull
        val date: LocalDateTime,
        @field:Schema(description = "Number")
        @field:Size(max = 27)
        val number_a: String?,
        @field:Schema(
            minimum = "0",
            maximum = Int.MAX_VALUE.toString(),
            description = "Count"
        )
        val count: Int = 1,
        @field:ArraySchema(
            schema = Schema(
                maxLength = 2147483646,
                required = false
            ),
            arraySchema = Schema(
                description = "Comment",
            ),
            maxItems = Int.MAX_VALUE,
        )
        val comments: List<String>
    )
```